# What should be my next workout plan?

Tags: strength, training

I was doing my workout for nearly 8 months continuously without any break, but unfortunately I was forced to take a break for 3 months. This past week  I started to go to the gym, doing some cardio. For weight training, I am confused about where to begin. So please help me with a workout plan to regain my strength.

I used to do squats with 60 kg on both sides, and lunges with 20 to 25 kg on both sides, deadlift with almost 90 kg. Once, I lifted 120 kgs.

I also need a diet plan with supplements. I used to take GNC Wheybolic and supplements like multivitamin tabs and liv5s.

Comment: Do you mean you squatted 140 kg (bar + 60 + 60) and deadlifted 200 kg (bar + 90 + 90), or was the deadlift total 90 kg?

Comment: What were you doing before the break and did you enjoy it?

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to choosing a plan after such a long break, a good approach will be treating yourself as of a beginner. That means starting with a full body workout about 3 times a week. The reason for doing that is to let your body accommodate to the "new" stress it's going through.

Don't avoid compound & heavy exercises such as deadlift and squat, but don't go too heavy too soon: in this "coming back" period, maintain a relatively high repetitions range for such exercises (8± per set), start with light weight and increase it rapidly from day to day.

After about 4-6 weeks, it will be a good time to move on to your next plan based on your goals.

Answer (score 0):

It's irrelevant what you used to do.
You may have some head start with weight lifting but if you haven't lifted in a while , you probably lost a nice amount of strength.
Either way pick a beginner weight lifting program like starting strength or 5x5 stronglifts and it will help you progress properly and safely. It will help you choose your starting weight also.
There is no need to do a full body workout at this stage
You don't need any supplements.
If you don't get in enough nutrients you can take a multivitamin

Comment: Aren't Starting Strength and 5x5 Stronglifts full body workout programs?

Comment: They are made of compound movements, only 3 moves per workout

Comment: So when you say there's no need to do a full body workout at this stage, aren't you suggesting full body workouts?

Comment: It's also not irrelevant what he used to do. Training effects last, and neuromuscualr traits remain. That's one reason that training comes back much faster the second time around.

Comment: I'm well aware..it is irrelevant because he was still a beginner lifter as he had only lifted for 8 months. So he still should be doing a beginner program. All beginner programs will adjust to your current strength, so it should not change his decision therefore irrelevant. He may start at a higher weight than other beginners will start on however it will not be because he worked out in the past rather because he currently is stronger